# Redefined Catch unit tests

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, catch-unit-test

I'm testing a huge piece of software and would like to use Catch for this task.
I'm using the "single include" version 1.9, integrating it in Visual Studio 2012 update 4 and using C++04 standard.

As you will see below, I use three ".cpp" files. Each of them reference:

- a include file providing "abstraction" macros (eg. `#define Assert(x) REQUIRE(x)`);
- a utility file providing... utilities for the test;
- the specific test target include files;
- some "using namespace" statement, all cpp files "using" the same namespace;
- the actual tests, written with the macros (eg. `Assert(2 == getNumber())`).

More details on the files content below.

This configuration works, but one of the test file is growing bigger by the day and I would like to split it in 3, or more. Now, say that I do the following:

- take part of the content of a test `test.cpp` and move it in a new file `test2.cpp`;
- add the same includes and defines to make it compile;
- include the new file in my main

this error pops up when I run the tests:

```
=============================
No tests ran
error: TEST_CASE( "test 2" ) already defined.
    First seen at c:\tests\catchtest2\catchtest2\test2.cpp(3)
    Redefined at c:\tests\catchtest2\catchtest2\test2.cpp(3)
```

where `test2.cpp` is the new file.
If I move the content back to `test.cpp` it all works, but working with tests thousands of lines long is almost harder than working on the project itself, and the dimension could grow 3, 4 times bigger still.
Is there a way to split the tests in multiple files?

-- NOTES --

I reckon including Catch in a header and using the including header instead of `catch.cpp` directly is not a good idea, but I successfully used this configuration with 3 (exactly 3) included `.cpp` test files, and am unable to use this with 4 files.

I remember reading that it was somehow related to the *line* at which the components were defined, but I can also move the code so that the test cases are defined at different lines and the behaviour doesn't change.

I also tried to "clean and rebuild", because it may well be that dirty data is kept in the compiler / linker's caches, but to no avail.

I couldn't create an actual MWE right now, so I gave you a sketch of the test setup as accurate as I thought it could be needed. I'm more than willing to provide additional details or try and build an actual MWE and share it.

Any idea is appreciated!

---

My "working" code looks like this:

**main.cpp**

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "test1.cpp"
#include "test2.cpp"
#include "test3.cpp"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    cleanDir("c:\\temp");
    init (argv);
    int result = Catch::Session().run( argc, argv );
    return ( result < 0xff ? result : 0xff );
}
```

**test1.cpp**

```
#include "unitTestSuite.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "systemundertest.h"

using namespace system::under::test;

my_test_case("test 1") {
    my_section("does X") {
        // tests...
    }
}

my_test_case("test 2") {
    my_section("does Y") {
        // tests...
    }
}
```

**unitTestSuite.h**

```
#ifndef UNIT_TEST_SUITE
#define UNIT_TEST_SUITE 1

#include "catch.hpp"
#define my_test_case(x) TEST_CASE("Testing: " x)
... // here is also a namespace with some unit test specific utils
#endif
```

**utils.h**

```
#ifndef _UTILS_
#define _UTILS_
// some global variables declared here and defined in utils.cpp
// template functions defined in the header
// non-template functions defined in utils.cpp
// a test generation namespace with some template functions and some non-template functions defined in utils.cpp
#endif
```

---

After the "split":

**test1.cpp**

```
#include "unitTestSuite.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "systemundertest.h"

using namespace system::under::test;

my_test_case("test 1") {
    my_section("does X") {
        // tests...
    }
}
```

**test1.2.cpp**

```
#include "unitTestSuite.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "systemundertest.h"

using namespace system::under::test;

my_test_case("test 2") {
    my_section("does Y") {
        // tests...
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "test1.cpp"
#include "test1.2.cpp"
#include "test2.cpp"
#include "test3.cpp"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    cleanDir("c:\\temp");
    init (argv);
    int result = Catch::Session().run( argc, argv );
    return ( result < 0xff ? result : 0xff );
}
```

**program output:**

```
=============================
No tests ran
error: TEST_CASE( "test 2" ) already defined.
    First seen at c:\tests\catchtest2\catchtest2\test1.2.cpp(3)
    Redefined at c:\tests\catchtest2\catchtest2\test1.2.cpp(3)
```

Comment: Why are you including cpp files?

Comment: It seems this is how catch manages tests.. i tried including headers and defining tests in separate cpp files, but got 8 assertions running instead of 1750 so i guess something went wrong ^^"

Comment: I think your main.cpp needs only the first two lines. You can link the object files from the test cpp’s into the same executable as that built with main.cpp. As a rule of thumb, if you include a cpp file you’re doing something odd.

Comment: Hmm, all catch examples use this pattern so I thought it was mandatory for the "catch magic" to happen. I will try to remove the cpp references and get back to this thread, thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: Do you have a reference for the examples? I’m quite happy to be re-educated if needs be.

Comment: For catch2 the help file at "scaling up": https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#scaling-up recommends to avoid putting tests in headers and talks about "using as many cpp files as needed", but it actually says nothing about them having to be included.

Comment: @jbcoe, you were right: the documentation examples show that it's not needed to include cpp files, and I successfully split files without including them. The odd thing is, I had the "8 assertions" problem until I created new source files and moved the code there. I guess it's something related to some strange VisualStudio cache, or the like. If you post the "don't include cpp files, just add them to the project" proposal as an answer I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don’t include the cpp files, just add them to the project. 
Your main.cpp file only needs the first two lines (a define and an include).